# How can i move textfield down When UIView is expanded (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiview, expandablelistview, textfield, expandable

This is my code in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    expandView.frame.size.height = 36
}
```

When i Press Expand Button

```
@IBAction func expandPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(expandView.frame.size.height == 36)
    {
        expandView.frame.size.height = 200;
    }
    else
    {
        expandView.frame.size.height = 36;
    }
}
```

This is the what i am getting as output, It is covering my next text field.  How can i make **Address textField** move down if the view is expanded?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the textfield frame in the function:

```
if(expandView.frame.size.height == 36){
    expandView.frame.size.height = 200;
    textfield.frame.origin.y = textfield.frame.origin.y + 164
}
else{
    expandView.frame.size.height = 36;
    textfield.frame.origin.y = textfield.frame.origin.y - 164
}
```

hope help you!
This is the result:

[image]

Comment: you could animate it with this, too... `UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { 
            // your code here
        }
`